# Alert in add_filter WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, alert

I found this function to only let 1 product be in cart at a time.
It works fine but I want to alert something in jQuery in the function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );   
function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) { 
   wc_empty_cart();
   return $passed;

    $message = "Add only 1 product";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";      
}
```

Can someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add jQuery alert using below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );   
function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) { 
   wc_empty_cart();

    $message = "Add only 1 product";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

    return $passed;      
}
```

Comment: You can check other options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851528/how-to-pop-an-alert-message-box-using-php