# Activating TOAST messages via _POST / _GET (mdl)

Tags: javascript, php, material-design-lite

After successful or unsuccessful execution of a PHP script, i want to display the execution result on the site in the form of a pop-up notification. How can I do this better?
Let's say I pass the result via _GET or _POST
Is it possible to use a toast for this, something like:

```
if (isset $_POST['message']) {
$message = $_POST['message'];
showmessage("$message");
}
```

I know that in PHP there is no such thing as ShowMessage, but I’m not very strong in JS.

Comment: If you want a simple alert box, then you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851528/how-to-pop-an-alert-message-box-using-php

Comment: Popups are done using HTML/CSS and maybe Javascript. Your PHP script can `echo` the necessary HTML/CSS for the browser to then display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php to echo out a script block:

```
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('SUCCES!');</script>"; 
   exit;
}
```